# Submitting a topology to Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I have configured Storm on my machine. Zookeeper, Nimbus and Supervisor are running properly.
Now I want to submit a topology to this storm.
I am trying to use storm jar.
but I am not able to submit it.
Can anybody please give an example for this.
It will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is in the [official documentation](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster), and it is clear enough. Run `storm jar path/to/allmycode.jar org.me.MyTopology arg1 arg2 arg3` (replace with  your project name and arguments if any). Make sure you are using StormSubmitter object instead of LocalCluster.

Comment: I cloned storm-starter

then as written there, everthing is working correcly when i execute
$ lein deps
$ lein compile
$ java -cp $(lein classpath) storm.starter.ExclamationTopology

Comment: then as wriiten in documentation I thought I should run java jar to submit Explanation topology of storm-starter, for this I created a .jar file from classes of these topologies in starter.then I exectued #bin/storm    jar/home/mahi/stormstarter/target/classes/storm/starter/try1.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology mytopology

Comment: But it gives error Error: Could not find or load main class storm.starter.ExclamationTopology Am I on right path...please Help:(

Comment: @MahiSingh Here is the problem. You asked a simple question, and I gave the simple answer. If you are facing specific issues, you should clearly describe it in your question in the first place. There is no way otherwise for us for predict and figure out how and why you are facing these problems.   Anyway, now looking at your comments, it looks like the class name you gave `storm.starter.ExclamationTopology` is not what you have set up, or maybe your code was not correctly compiled. Again, explain in detail and you will get help.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, almost all the examples on the internet show the word counter example, and do not mention the steps required in a simple way:

All you need to do is this:
1. Navigate to your storm bin folder:
`cd /Users/nav/programming/apache-storm-1.0.1/bin`
2. Start nimbus
`./storm nimbus`
3. Start supervisor
`./storm supervisor`
4. Start the ui program
`./storm ui`
5. Make sure you build your jar file with the [storm jar excluded](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=exclude%20storm%20jar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=iu9HV7TiBe-K8Qew966ADw) from it.
6. Make sure your `/Users/nav/programming/apache-storm-1.0.1/conf/storm.yaml` [file is valid](http://www.yamllint.com/) (this should've been step 2).
7. Make sure that in your code, you are submitting the topology using `StormSubmitter.submitTopology`
8. Navigate to the storm bin folder again
`cd /Users/nav/programming/apache-storm-1.0.1/bin`
9. Submit your jar file to storm
`./storm jar /Users/nav/myworkspace/StormTrial/build/libs/StormTrial.jar com.abc.stormtrial.StormTrial`
The above command is basically just this:
`stormExecutable jarOption pathToYourJarFile theClassContainingYourMainFile`

If you want to pass commandline arguments to your program, add it at the end:
`stormExecutable jarOption pathToYourJarFile theClassContainingYourMainFile commandlineArguments`

Here, `com.abc.stormtrial` is the full package name and `.StormTrial` is the name of the class that contains your `main` function.

Now open up your browser and type `http://127.0.0.1:8080` and you'll see your topology running via Storm's UI.

Comment: when i execute 9th step, it runs the .py script in a new window and exits without any error/info. any idea why?

Comment: Check the storm UI and you should see the topology running there.